# How to manage concurrent development with mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, workflow, dvcs, mercurial-queue

This is a best practice question, and I expect the answer to be "it depends". I just hope to learn more real world scenarios and workflows.

First of all, I'm talking about different changes for the same project, so no subrepo please.

Let's say you have your code base in an hg repository. You start to work on a complicated new feature A, then a complicated bug B is reported by your trusted tester (you have testers, right?).

It's trivial if (the fix for) B depends on A. You simlply ci A then ci B.

My question is what to do when they are independent (or at least it seems now).

I can think of the following ways:

1. Use a separate clone for B.
2. Use anonymous or named branches, or bookmarks, in the same repository.
3. Use MQ (with B patch on top of A).
4. Use branched MQ (I'll explain later).
5. Use multiple MQ (since 1.6)

1 and 2 are covered by an [excellent blog](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/08/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial/) by @Steve Losh linked from a [slightly related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405604/managing-release-branches-in-mercurial).

The one huge advantage of 1 over the other choices is that it doesn't require any rebuild when you switch from working on one thing to the other, because the files are physically separated and independent. So it's really the only choice if, for example, A and/or B touches a header file that defines a tri-state boolean and is included by thousands of C files (don't tell me you haven't seen such a legacy code base).

3 is probably the easiest (in terms of setup and overhead), and you can flip the order of A and B if B is a small and/or urgent fix. However it can get tricky if A and B touches the same file(s). It's easy to fix patch hunks that  failed to apply if A and B changes are orthogonal within the same file(s), but conceptually it's still a bit risky.

4 can make you dizzy but it's the most powerful and flexible and scalable way. I default `hg qinit` with `-c` since I want to mark work-in-progress patches and push/pull them, but it does take a conceptual leap to realize that you can branch in MQ repo too. Here are the steps (mq = hg --mq):

1. `hg qnew bugA`; make changes for A; `hg qref`
2. `mq branch branchA; hg qci`
3. `hg qpop; mq up -rtip^`
4. `hg qnew bugB`; make changes for B; `hg qref`
5. `mq branch branchB; hg qci`
6. To work on A again: `hg qpop; mq up branchA; hg qpush`

It seems crazy to take so many steps, and whenever you need to switch work you must `hg qci; hg qpop; mq up <branch>; hg qpush`. But consider this: you have several named release branches in the same repository, and you need to work on several projects and bug fixes at the same time for all of them (you'd better get guaranteed bonus for this kind of work). You'd get lost very soon with the other approaches.

Now my fellow hg lovers, are there other/better alternatives?

---

(UPDATE) `qqueue` almost makes #4 obsolete. See Steve Losh's elegant description [here](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/08/a-git-users-guide-to-mercurial-queues/#multiple-patch-queues).

Comment: As if it's not obvious, I'm asking for an hg-based approach. But if you can give me a single command from another SCM that works in all cases, I'm ditching hg. Consider it a challenge, git aficionados.

Comment: I think you need to specify your problem a little better.  Why doesn't this work for all cases:  fix bug A, commit its patch, fix bug B, commit its patch?

Comment: Sorry that I rambled a bit, Spolsky-ishly. I mentioned one simple case: "if B is a small and/or urgent fix". A more realistic situation is that A and B are both long projects that takes a lot of commits and iterations. Also if you have a code review process like my company does, you may have finished A and sent it out for review, and you can't sit there twiddling your thumbs waiting for the reviewers so you have to go pick up B in the meanwhile. But then the reviewer may blast your code and you have to make changes to please him/her. So there can be countless project switches along the way.

Comment: I just saw an answer(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/970669/how-to-swap-mercurial-queues-in-and-out-of-a-repository/970905#970905) covering 1 and 4 for a more elaborate example.

Comment: Well, it seems like you are just working alone on this project. If you were working in a team, you would probably never even ask this question, because parallel development would be something you simply do and take the relative cost of it in stride with it.

While doing parallel development, the best practice is clearly a named branch for every feature and subsequent merge down to trunk when the feature or bug is done, with as many merge ups from the trunk to your branch as necessary to stay current on other changes during the development of this feature. Not merging down before you run tests.

Comment: @Jiri Klouda: yes the question is for single developer. We do have a moderately sized and distributed team, and we do use similar strategies of named-branch and merging as you mentioned. But none of us has the luxury to work on only one thing at a time, especially given our rigid code review/approval process, which may drag on for quite a while.

Comment: @GeoffreyZheng did you have a look at pbranch http://arrenbrecht.ch/mercurial/pbranch/ ?

Comment: @tonfa thanks for the info. It looks like a good mix between regular hg branches and MQ branches with the advantage being the branches are always there. However I'm a bit leery of non-bundled extensions with significant feature/behavior change, plus I can use mq to achieve what it does with only a few extra steps. One note is that I use mq only during development, and will `qfinish` as soon as code review starts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like there's no more or better choices than the ones I listed in the question. So here they are again.

1. Use one clone per project.

   - Pros: total separation, thus no rebuild when switching projects.
   - Cons: toolchain needs to switch between two clones.
2. Use anonymous or named branches, or bookmarks, in the same repository.

   - Pros: standard hg (or any DVCS) practice; clean and clear.
   - Cons: must commit before switching and rebuild after.
3. Use MQ with one patch (or multiple consecutive patches) per project.

   - Pros: simple and easy.
   - Cons: must `qrefresh` before switching and rebuild after; tricky and risky if projects are not orthogonal.
4. Use one MQ branch (or `qqueue` in 1.6+) per project.

   - Pros: ultra flexible and scalable (for the number of concurrent projects)
   - Cons: must `qrefresh` and `qcommit` before switching and rebuild after; feels complicated.

Like always, there's no silver bullet, so pick and choose the one right for the job.

---

(UPDATE) For anyone who's in love with MQ, using MQ on top of regular branches (#2 + #3) is probably the most common and preferable practice.

If you have two concurrent projects with baseline on two branches (for example next release and current release), it's trivial to hop between them like this:

```
hg qnew; {coding}; hg qrefresh; {repeat}
hg qfinish -a
hg update -r <branch/bookmark/rev>
hg qimport -r <rev>; {repeat}
```

For the last step, `qimport` should add a `-a` option to import a line of changesets at once. I hope [Meister Geisler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/110204/martin-geisler) notices this :)

Answer (score 7):

I would always use named branches, because that lets Mercurial do its job: to keep your project history, and to remember why you made which changes in what order to your source code. Whether to have one clone or two sitting on your disk is generally an easy one, given my working style, at least:

1. Does your project lack a build process, so that you can test and run things right from the source code? Then I will be tempted to have just one clone, and `hg up` back and forth when I need to work on another branch.
2. But if you have a buildout, virtualenv, or other structure that gets built, and that might diverge between the two branches, then doing an `hg up` then waiting for the build process to re-run can be a big pain, especially if things like setting up a sample database are involved. In that case I would definitely use two clones, one sitting at the tip of trunk, and one sitting at the tip of the emergency feature branch.

Comment: I voted up but didn't accept this because I mentioned named branch myself, and I was asking for alternatives :) We do have a build process (not very modern, like the code base itself), so #2 is indeed the argument for using two clones. However it can be a pain to switch your debug workflow between the two clones, for example you'd need two launch configurations in Eclipse.

Comment: As an alternative to named branches, you could number them :) In other words, there is no good alternative, wheel already invented.

Answer (score 1):

So the question is, at the point when you are told to stop working on feature A, and begin independent feature B, what alternative options are there, for: How to manage concurrent development with mercurial?

Let's look at the problem with concurrency removed, the same way you write threaded code- define a simple work flow for solving any problem given to you, and apply it to each problem. Mercurial will join the work, once it's done. So, programmer A will work on feature A. Programmer B will work on feature B. Both just happen to be you. (If only we had multi-core brains:)

> I would always use named branches, because that lets Mercurial do its job: to keep your project history, and to remember why you made which changes in what order to your source code.

I agree with Brandon's sentiment, but I wonder if he overlooked that feature A has not been tested? In the worst case, the code compiles and passes unit tests, **but some methods implement the previous requirements, and some methods implement the new ones.** A diff against the previous check-in is the tool I would use to help me get back on track with feature A.

**Is your code for feature A at a point when you would normally check it in?** Switching from feature A to working on feature B is not a reason to commit code to the head or to a branch. Only check in code that compiles and passes your tests. **My reason is, if programmer C needs to begin feature C, a fresh checkout of this branch is no longer the best place to start.** Keeping your branch heads healthy, means you can respond quickly, with more reliable bug fixes.

The goal is to have your (tested and verified) code running, so you want all your code to end up merged into the head (of your development and legacy branches). My point seems to be, I've seen branching used inefficiently: code becomes stale and then not used, the merge becomes harder than the original problem.

Only your option 1 makes sense to me. In general:

1. You should think your code works, before someone else sees it.
2. Favor the head over a branch.
3. Branch and check-in if someone else is picking up the problem.
4. Branch if your automated system or testers need your code only.
5. Branch if you are part of a team, working on a problem. Consider it the head, see 1-4.

With the exception of config files, the build processes should be a checkout and a single build command. It should not be any more difficult to switch between clones, than for a new programmer to join the project. (I'll admit my project needs some work here.)

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it seems like you're addressing it within the context of a traditional (centralized) VCS like svn. In hg (or any DVCS) your commits are local until they are pushed/pulled, so it's perfect safe (and recommended) to commit before testing.

Comment: I mostly use svn, so I'm sure it affects my perspective. In hg, after a push, does the log show a difference between the push commit, and local commits? Do you use github? It's great, but it can be difficult to figure out which repository to clone- which fork contains the bug fixes you need, or which is active vs abandoned. Coming back to branching, I can see how many commit points helps the author. I think you're saying hg protects other developers from seeing the interim commits, because they are not pushed. I think integration tests are where this might not be true.

Comment: sorry I didn't notice your comment. Once commits (more accurately, changesets) are pushed, they're no longer local. The log doesn't show whether a changeset has been pushed. The `outgoing` command tells you if it hasn't. There's no "protection" on the local commits. Anyone can pull them if they want to.