# Mercurial Patch Queue Use Cases

Tags: mercurial, patch, mercurial-queue

I use mercurial patches in the following cases:-

1. **When I need to pull from a remote repository and have outstanding uncommitted changes**. Then I simply create a patch, qpop it, pull from the remote repository, and then import the patch again.
2. **When I need to upload patches to reviewboards**. I simply make a patch and upload it.

How else do you use Mercurial Patch Queues? I feel that its a very powerful Mercurial extension and that I am not using it to its fullest potential.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Mercurial wiki has a [good section](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MqTutorial#Why_would_I_want_to_use_mq.3F) on use cases:

In summary:

1. Saving the current state of the working copy so you can easily revert to it later on
2. Preventing a "tangled working copy" - if you're halfway through a change and want to change something else
3. Provide mutable, rearrangeable commits so you can get 'history' looking just right before pushing.

Answer (score 4):

You don't really need Mercurial patches for this.  If you have outstanding uncommited changes when you pull, they will be merged with the tip.

#### Example:

```
C:\>hg init db
C:\>cd db
C:\db>echo >file1
C:\db>echo >file2
C:\db>echo >file3
C:\db>hg ci -Am codebase          # Create a code base with 3 files.
adding file1
adding file2
adding file3
C:\db>echo a change >>file2       # Outstanding change to file2.
C:\db>hg st
M file2
```

At this point we'll clone the database and commit a change that we can pull.

```
C:\db>hg clone . \db2
updating to branch default
3 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
C:\db>cd \db2
C:\db2>echo a change >>file3
C:\db2>hg ci -m "file3 change"    # Commit a change to file3.
```

Back in the original database...

```
C:\db2>cd \db
C:\db>hg st                       # Still have uncommitted change
M file2
C:\db>hg pull \db2
pulling from \db2
searching for changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 1 changesets with 1 changes to 1 files
(run 'hg update' to get a working copy)
C:\db>hg st                       # We have the new history, but haven't updated.
M file2                           # file2 has uncommitted change.
C:\db>type file3                  # file3 is unchanged. 
ECHO is on.
C:\db>hg update
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
C:\db>hg st                       # We've updated, and file2 *still* has
M file2                           #    uncommitted change.
C:\db>type file2
ECHO is on.
a change
C:\db>type file3                  # But file3 now has committed change
ECHO is on.                       #    that was pulled.
a change
```

So the moral is, you can just pull and update, even with uncommitted changes.  If there are merge conflicts, normal merge behavior occurs as well.

For patch exporting `hg export <rev>` will export patches for review.

Comment: About patches, it is great deal harder with MQ when you're working with many patches that may or may not stack upon on another. The idea of popping out a patch when it is not needed is lost.

Answer (score 4):

When you create a patch queue on Bitbucket, it lists some of the common uses for patch queues in the right pane. Their explanation is very good and answers your question directly. Quotes from it are below.

#### Patch queues are good for:

> - **Developing features you intend to submit for upstream review**
>
>   Because patches in patch queues can
>     be modified, they provide an ideal way
>     to develop a feature in a
>     history-tracked manner, while still
>     allowing you to easily incorporate
>     feedback
> - **Experimenting with adding a new feature**
>
>   Patch queues don't clutter your
>     project's history, so you can safely
>     use them as a way to quickly try out
>     an idea, and keeping it in version
>     control, without cluttering up your
>     project's history with failed
>     excursions. If you decide to keep the
>     experiment, you can easily turn a
>     patch queue into a set of traditional
>     Mercurial commits
> - **Maintaining private customizations for another project**
>
>   Because patch queues are not part of
>     the official change log for a project,
>     they are ideal for maintaining private
>     customizations for an upstream
>     project. For example, you might
>     maintain a patch queue that makes
>     program better integrate with your
>     company's workflow

#### Patch queues are *not* good for

> - **Long-running branches**
>
>   Because patch queues are highly
>     volatile, they do a poor job tracking
>     the long-term history of your source
>     code. For this reason, long-running
>     branches, such as those that
>     correspond to product releases, should
>     be kept in repositories or named
>     branches.
> - **Group development**
>
>   Patch queues do not track merge
>     history, which makes them a poor
>     choice for doing group development,
>     where you really wish to see when a
>     given set of features was merged into
>     a repository. When in doubt, you
>     should stick to a traditional fork,
>     but mastering the power of patch
>     queues will give you tremendous
>     flexibility in your workflow, and
>     provide you with greatly enhanced
>     collaboration abilities.

Answer (score 1):

MQ is a great tool to manage concurrent development. Blatant self-plagiarism and self-promotion from my own [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719019/how-to-manage-concurrent-development-with-mercurial/4057072#4057072):

> 3 Use MQ with one patch (or multiple consecutive patches) per project.
>
> - Pros: simple and easy.
> - Cons: must qrefresh before switching and rebuild after; tricky
>     and risky if projects are not
>     orthogonal.
>
> 4 Use one MQ branch per project.
>
> - Pros: ultra flexible and scalable (for the number of concurrent
>     projects)
> - Cons: must qrefresh and qcommit before switching and rebuild after;
>     feels complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I use MQ for developing on top of a big Subversion repository I don't want to checkout with hgsubversion or something similar. In my working folder I initiate a new .hg repo and a Mercurial Patch Queue. I track the svn revisions with HG and my patches are on top. Whenever I feel to update the svn state, I pop all the patches, run `svn update` and push and refresh the patches again. When I'm confident my series is okay for commit, I can qfinish my patches one by one. (Currently a new Subversion feature "shelve" is under development, but every time I tried that, it did not work well enough, so I still use that MQ approach.)